# How to retrieve wanted string with re from lines

Tags: python, regex, string, extract

```
 Tue Aug 21 17:02:26 2018 (gtgrhrthrhrhrthhhthrthrhrh)
 fjfpjpgporejpejgjr[eh[[[jh[j[ej[[ej[ej[e]]]]
 fkw[kgkeg[ekrk[ekg[kergk[erkg[eg[kg]
 Tue Aug 21 17:31:06 2018 ( ijwejfwfjwpfjwf[[few[jjfwfefwfeffeww]]
 fiowhfiweohewhfpwfhpfhpepwehfphpwhfpehfpwfh
 f,wfpewfefewgpwpg,pewgp
 Tue Aug 21 18:10:42 2018 ( reijpjfpjejferjfrejfpjefjer
 k[pfk[epkf[kr[ek[ke[gkk]
 r[g[keprkgpekg[rkg[pkg[ekg]
```

Above is an example of the content in the text file. I want to extract a string with `re`. 
How should I construct the `findall` condition to achieve the expected result below?  I have tried the following:

```
  match=re.findall(r'[Tue\w]+2018$',data2)
```

but it is not working. I understand that $ is the symbol for the end of the string. How can I do it?

Expected Result is:

```
  Tue Aug 21 17:02:26 2018
  Tue Aug 21 17:31:06 2018
  Tue Aug 21 18:10:42 2018
           .
           .
           .
```

Comment: $ is the symbol for the end of the line, not the string you're looking for. The expression you used would only return a match if the last thing in the line was 2018.

Comment: In addition you may find similar pattern via `re.search(r'(^\w{2,3}\s+\w{2,3}[^(]+)', line)`.

Comment: Since UnbearableLightness already answered your question and I expressed my opinion in the comments, providing another answer would be redundant. I'll try to explain why your pattern didn't work.

Comment: `[Tue\w]+` matches one or more characters inside the brackets. `T`, `u`, `e`, and `\w`. the Tue is already included in `\w` so there isn't much of a point to that. You didn't include a space or `\s` so nothing matched. Also, `$` means that your line ends at that point, and in this case, "2018" was not the end of the line.

Comment: That being said, are there other days of the week and/or years, or just Tuesday and 2018?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pattern:

```
^Tue.*?2018
```

- `^` Assert position beginning of line.
- `Tue` Literal substring.
- `.*?` Match anything lazily.
- `2018` Match literal substring.

Since you are working with a multiline string and you want to match pattern at the beginning of a string, you have to use the `re.MULTILINE` flag.

```
import re
mystr="""
Tue Aug 21 17:02:26 2018 (gtgrhrthrhrhrthhhthrthrhrh)
fjfpjpgporejpejgjr[eh[[[jh[j[ej[[ej[ej[e]]]]
fkw[kgkeg[ekrk[ekg[kergk[erkg[eg[kg]
Tue Aug 21 17:31:06 2018 ( ijwejfwfjwpfjwf[[few[jjfwfefwfeffeww]]
fiowhfiweohewhfpwfhpfhpepwehfphpwhfpehfpwfh
f,wfpewfefewgpwpg,pewgp
Tue Aug 21 18:10:42 2018 ( reijpjfpjejferjfrejfpjefjer
k[pfk[epkf[kr[ek[ke[gkk]
r[g[keprkgpekg[rkg[pkg[ekg]
"""

print(re.findall(r'^Tue.*?2018',mystr,re.MULTILINE))
```

Prints:

```
['Tue Aug 21 17:02:26 2018', 'Tue Aug 21 17:31:06 2018', 'Tue Aug 21 18:10:42 2018']
```

Comment: That does not "break" anything. OP wants to match strings with start with `Tue` and end with 2018/four digits.

Comment: If such a sentence was a case OP should add it to his question. Until then, it's all speculation.

Comment: Did you check the example? What about dates that aren't 2018? What about 2 instances of "2018" in one line?

Comment: Read my latest comment ^.

Comment: At the very least you should make it non-greedy to at least be a little bit more accurate. `^Tue.*?2018`. If you don't understand the question or the requirements are incomplete you should ask questions.

Comment: Can you define "accurate" ?

Comment: It's better to over-do it and cover all your bases than potentially damage the integrity of thousands of lines of data. Then again it probably isn't that necessary for small cases

Comment: Regex is about matching patterns. The pattern from OP sample text is clear. There is no point in making the regex more complicated than it needs to be. If OP wants to clarify himself, he will.

Comment: I added the lazy quantifier as you suggested @emsimpson92, perhaps you can remove your downvote now.

Comment: I have a question what if I I dont use (.*?) , how can I replace this? I have a little difficulty with including whitespace expression in the condition. I tried using      re.findall(r'T\w+\s+A\w+'), but its not working. How do I deal with the whitespace? The above expression is T follows by \w+ and \s (which ought to include the whitespace and then A, am I right?